# Highcharts: generate blank chart

Tags: highcharts

My application takes in dynamic data and generates a chart, with an option to display a message overlayed on top using `chart.renderer.text()`.

Sometimes the dynamic request for data is malformed, and the resultant data unreliable, so in that case I'd like to generate a completely blank chart (with custom background colour) *of the same width and height as originally requested* (that part of the request is usually OK), and just with a message overlay as described above to display a message to the user.

What is the easiest way of doing that?  I want the blank chart to be literally that... just a solid colour with no axes or anything, and no message about "no data to display" which I've seen on a couple of examples I found when searching for an answer.  And on top of the blank background (with the user-defined width and height) my message overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the easiest create... empty chart. Then in `load` event add necessary text to the chart. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zkj36o7e/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var text = this.renderer.text("Malformed data").attr({
                    'text-anchor': "middle",                 // SVG's text-align ;)
                    stroke: "black",                         // color
                    opacity: 0,                              // smooth animation - part I  
                    x: this.plotWidth / 2 + this.plotLeft    // x-center of the plot
                }).add(),
                    bbox = text.getBBox();                   // get bounding box of the created text 

                text.attr({
                    y: this.plotHeight / 2 - bbox.height / 2 // y-position - half of the text's height
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1                               // smooth animation - part II
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks.  I had tried something along those lines, but it wasn't working.  It's likely to be something else in my code that's causing me problems.

Comment: Specifically, I'm getting a `Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13` error.  My code is structured a bit more like the following (just a re-hash of your example): http://jsfiddle.net/zkj36o7e/2/.  I'm wondering whether it's a timing issue, with the 'container' element not being "ready" before the chart is created with 'renderTo' set to 'container'.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing live demo. Make sure you are creating chart onload event (for example inside: `$(function() { ... });`). Also, make sure your container exists (double check ID's - maybe some typo?).

Comment: Yes, this is what I can't understand.  The code is definitely inside `$(function() { ... });)` (as per jsfiddle.net/zkj36o7e/2) so it should only reference 'container' once 'container' is actually ready. In fact, it all works fine when a full set of chart options / data is generated, but as soon as I bypass options/data generation (and just return a very basic chart options with `renderTo`, `width` and `height`) it gives that #13 error... nothing else in the html or js has changed (e.g. no typo in 'container').  Very peculiar.

Comment: Without live demo is hard to say what is wrong, sorry. Is you website available online? If not, can you setup simple demo with some fake data to recreate issue?

Comment: OK now I feel dumb.  The issue was that my 'core' chart options (to create the blank chart) were not nested within a `chart` element.  D'oh!  So I had `options = { renderTo: 'container', width: 310, height: 350 }` instead of `options = { chart: { renderTo: 'container', width: 310, height: 350 } }`.  Anyhow, it's been a useful lesson.